# Aborted (core dumped) on tf_trt create_inference_graph

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6, tensorrt

I am trying to convert a `ssdLite_mobilenet_V2` from TensorFlow to `tensorrt` using `tf_trt` as per the instructions mentioned in this [link][1]. I am getting `Aborted (core dumped)` error. The really weird thing is that I've done the exact same thing (with the same program) on the same graph architecture but trained on another set and it runs without an error.

OS : Ubuntu 18.04.2 
GPU: Tesla M60
TensorFlow 1.13.1

I've tried to modify max_batch_size and max_workspace_size_bytes. But the problem doesn't seem to come from an overflow of the GPU memory, it never seems to use more than 1.5G of memory on it.

````
import tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt as trt
import tensorflow as tf

frozen_graph, input_names, output_names = build_detection_graph(
    config="pipeline.config",
    checkpoint="model.ckpt-75000"
)
with tf.gfile.FastGFile('graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
trt_graph = trt.create_inference_graph(
    input_graph_def=frozen_graph,
    outputs=output_names,
    max_batch_size=1,
    max_workspace_size_bytes=1 << 25,
    precision_mode='FP16',
    minimum_segment_size=50
)

with open("graph.uff","wb") as f:
    f.write(uff_model.SerializeToString())```

2019-04-18 12:45:50.313642: I tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/segment/segment.cc:443] There are 169 ops of 35 different types in the graph that are not converted to TensorRT: Range, GreaterEqual, Greater, Split, TopKV2, Select, Less, Slice, Identity, BiasAdd, Reshape, Mul, Fill, Squeeze, Const, Unpack, ResizeBilinear, GatherV2, NonMaxSuppressionV3, Where, ExpandDims, Cast, Minimum, Sum, Sub, Pack, Transpose, Pad, ConcatV2, Exp, Placeholder, Add, Shape, NoOp, StridedSlice, (For more information see https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/dgx/integrate-tf-trt/index.html#support-ops).
2019-04-18 12:45:51.094322: I tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:913] Number of TensorRT candidate segments: 2
2019-04-18 12:45:51.146102: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/log/trt_logger.cc:34] DefaultLogger Half2 support requested on hardware without native FP16 support, performance will be negatively affected.
2019-04-18 12:46:15.758417: I tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:1015] TensorRT node TRTEngineOp_0 added for segment 0 consisting of 275 nodes succeeded.
2019-04-18 12:46:15.801363: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/log/trt_logger.cc:34] DefaultLogger Half2 support requested on hardware without native FP16 support, performance will be negatively affected.
2019-04-18 12:47:02.994309: I tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:1015] TensorRT node TRTEngineOp_1 added for segment 1 consisting of 684 nodes succeeded.
2019-04-18 12:47:03.494635: F tensorflow/core/graph/graph.cc:659] Check failed: inputs[edge->dst_input()] == nullptr Edge {name:'TRTEngineOp_1' id:1323 op device:{} def:{{{node TRTEngineOp_1}} = TRTEngineOp[InT=[DT_FLOAT], OutT=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], cached_engine_batches=[1], calibration_data="", fixed_input_size=true, input_shapes=[[1,300,300,3]], max_cached_engines_count=10, output_shapes=[[1,576,19,19], [1,1280,10,10], [1,512,5,5], [1,256,3,3], [1,24,3,3]], precision_mode="FP16", segment_funcdef_name="TRTEngineOp_1_native_segment", serialized_segment="\310\265\2...00\000\000", static_engine=true, use_calibration=false, workspace_size_bytes=11966231, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Preprocessor/stack, ^const6)}}:{name:'TRTEngineOp_0' id:1322 op device:{} def:{{{node TRTEngineOp_0}} = TRTEngineOp[InT=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], OutT=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], cached_engine_batches=[1], calibration_data="", fixed_input_size=true, input_shapes=[[1,256,3,3], [1,512,5,5], [1,1280,10,10], [1,576,19,19], [1,24,3,3]], max_cached_engines_count=10, output_shapes=[[1,1917,4], [1,1917,3]], precision_mode="FP16", segment_funcdef_name="TRTEngineOp_0_native_segment", serialized_segment="\360o\021\...00\000\000", static_engine=true, use_calibration=false, workspace_size_bytes=4810985, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_2_Conv2d_3_3x3_s2_256/Relu6, FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_2_Conv2d_2_3x3_s2_512/Relu6, FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/Conv_1/Relu6, FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_13/expansion_output, BoxPredictor_3/BoxEncodingPredictor/BiasAdd, ^Postprocessor/scale_logits/y, ^BoxPredictor_4/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases/read, ^BoxPredictor_5/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases/read, ^const6)}} with dst_input 0 and had pre-existing input edge {name:'TRTEngineOp_1' id:1323 op device:{} def:{{{node TRTEngineOp_1}} = TRTEngineOp[InT=[DT_FLOAT], OutT=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], cached_engine_batches=[1], calibration_data="", fixed_input_size=true, input_shapes=[[1,300,300,3]], max_cached_engines_count=10, output_shapes=[[1,576,19,19], [1,1280,10,10], [1,512,5,5], [1,256,3,3], [1,24,3,3]], precision_mode="FP16", segment_funcdef_name="TRTEngineOp_1_native_segment", serialized_segment="\310\265\2...00\000\000", static_engine=true, use_calibration=false, workspace_size_bytes=11966231, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Preprocessor/stack, ^const6)}}:{name:'TRTEngineOp_0' id:1322 op device:{} def:{{{node TRTEngineOp_0}} = TRTEngineOp[InT=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], OutT=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], cached_engine_batches=[1], calibration_data="", fixed_input_size=true, input_shapes=[[1,256,3,3], [1,512,5,5], [1,1280,10,10], [1,576,19,19], [1,24,3,3]], max_cached_engines_count=10, output_shapes=[[1,1917,4], [1,1917,3]], precision_mode="FP16", segment_funcdef_name="TRTEngineOp_0_native_segment", serialized_segment="\360o\021\...00\000\000", static_engine=true, use_calibration=false, workspace_size_bytes=4810985, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_2_Conv2d_3_3x3_s2_256/Relu6, FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_2_Conv2d_2_3x3_s2_512/Relu6, FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/Conv_1/Relu6, FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_13/expansion_output, BoxPredictor_3/BoxEncodingPredictor/BiasAdd, ^Postprocessor/scale_logits/y, ^BoxPredictor_4/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases/read, ^BoxPredictor_5/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases/read, ^const6)}}
Aborted (core dumped)





  [1]: https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/tf_trt_models
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you retry calling `create_inference_graph` with this argument `is_dynamic_op=True`.

Also it would be good to increase the verbosity of the tensorflow log using `TF_CPP_VMODULE=convert_graph=2,convert_nodes=2,segment=2,trt_engine=2 python ...`

Also check with the most recent tensorflow. You can try the nightly containers from dockerhub.

Comment: thanks a lot ! i've try with tensorflow-nightly-gpu and it seems to work ! i don't really see any big acceleration (less than 10 % ) but still thank you !